# Find distance of matching pixel in stereo images

Tags: c++, opencv

Given two images (left and right) i want to click on a pixel on the left image, and click the corresponding pixel on the right image. How can i calculate the distance of clicked pixel to the camera?

This is not real time. After doing this i will add color filter instead of clicking, but first i must achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, as it depends a lot on the geometry of the stereo setup.

Theoretically speaking, you'd convert both pixels to rays, and calculate the intersection point. Due to rounding errors, the rays are unlikely to intersect, so you need to find the point closest to both rays. The camera geometry comes in when you're converting pixels coordinates to ray equations.

Comment: Thanks, i have some information about camera geometry. I think you are talking about triangulation, however the method changes depending on the position of the object in terms of both cameras (eg. if the object is on the right of the left camera, and left of the right camera, a different formula is needed. But if the object is left or right of the both cameras, the formula changes)

Comment: @1.44mb: Actually, the formula I mentioned (ray intersection) doesn't. E.g. you can have two rays going left and intersecting to the left of the leftmost camera.